# How to run Node server through my IP address and router port forwarding

Tags: node.js, portforwarding

I am trying to access a super simple Node server through the web using my router's IP address. I've set up port forwarding on my router and I'm getting some really strange results.

The server is available through my internal IP on the correct port, 192.168.0.10:80, which *seems* to defaults to no port (by not keeping the :80 port designation). It also works internally on port 3000 (192.168.0.10:3000, without getting rid of the port designation).

But I when I try to access it from my public IP I get my router's login page, only when port forwarding and listening are set up for port 3000 (80 doesn't work).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Isolate the network and use `telnet <ip> <port>` to verify that your server is listening before adding any port forward, you need to be sure that you can access the server using the proper interface.

Comment: are you setting the IP your server is listening on? otherwise it's likely only accessible from the machine it's running on as it's binding to the loopback IP. ie you might need `server.listen(3000, '192.168.0.10');` or `server.listen(3000, '0.0.0.0');`